# Getting XAuth to work with Node.JS & OAuth

Tags: node.js, oauth, xauth, instapaper

I'm building my first node.js app, and trying to integrate it with the Instapaper API. Instapaper only uses XAuth, and I'm a little confused how it works.

Should I use the node-oauth module and try to customize it for xauth? Or should I roll my own xauth? Or something else, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd checkout something like [EveryAuth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth), see how they are handling the various options out there, forking it, and then contributing back with a new implementation.

Good luck man.

Comment: I'll try for sure. It's just that I'm new to javascript and oauth, and a little lost right now. I think I need to pass username and password parameters through the Authorization header. Now: what does that mean, in terms of code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get it working with the `oauth` module.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9645033/186101

You'd still need to handle storing the tokens for your users, but that answer should get you u and running for testing the API in node.